# Good method to parse value from PowerPivot PivotItem?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I have a PivotItem with the following `.name` and `.value` properties:

```
[dimCalendar].[MonthName].&[April 2013]
```

I am only interested in the part where it says `April 2013`.

What is a good method to parse or otherwise get this value from the PivotItem?

Comment: Use `Split` on the name, using "[" as the delimiter then just `Replace` to get rid of the trailing "]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the last one, this will work nicely :

```
Sub test_user1283776()
MsgBox get_PivotItem_From_PowerPivot("[dimCalendar].[MonthName].&[April 2013]")
End Sub

Function get_PivotItem_From_PowerPivot(PowerString As String) As String
    Dim A() As String
    A = Split(PowerString, ".&[")
    get_PivotItem_From_PowerPivot = Trim(Replace(A(UBound(A)), "]", ""))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution one: Split and replace**

`Split` would be best with `[` as the delimiter character. Get the upper bound of the `Split` array and replace the trailing `]` with `""`.

**Solution two: regular expressions**

Add `Microsoft VBregularexpression 5.5` as a reference.

```
Private Function Method(str As String) As String
Dim regexp As New regexp
regexp.Pattern = "\[.*\]\[.*\]\[(.*)\]"
Method = regexp.Replace(str, "$1")
End Function
```